# Cannot see the "Components" folder in Xamarin.forms /.netstandard project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new in xamarin and I am looking for a way to add some components in my android projet but I cannot see the "Components" folder when I create my project

Thanks in advance

Comment: Components are deprecated.

Comment: I see thanks for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are already using a Solution that has components added, you won't be able to view the components directory in VS. Instead you should use Nuget Packages.

https://blog.xamarin.com/hello-nuget-new-home-xamarin-components/

> In the upcoming releases of Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio for
>   Mac, both of which are currently available in preview, the Xamarin
>   Component Store is only visible in the IDE for developers whose
>   projects are currently using Xamarin Components in their apps.